# Remove nil items from end of array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Given an array like:

```
[1, 2, nil, nil, 3, nil, 4, 5, 6, nil, nil, nil]
```

id like to remove the `nil`'s from the end of the array. Not hard to solve with some ugly loops, but I was hoping there was a Ruby way to do it.

```
Result: [1, 2, nil, nil, 3, nil, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you would want the nil in between, but I digress!

```
array = [1, 2, nil, nil, 3, nil, 4, 5, 6, nil, nil, nil]
array.reverse.drop_while {|i| i == nil}.reverse
```

Comment: This is great. Didn't know about drop_while! Thank you.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you. As to why you would want the middle `nil`s - in my case, I have imported a CSV file which contains column headings - and also some 'white space' columns on the end of each line. The nils in the middle represent 'the user didn't include a value', whereas the trailing ones represent 'the spreadsheet export included dud columns'.

Answer (score 22):

How about this:

```
a.pop until a.last
```

Comment: Smart. Mayby too smart but +1 anyway.

Comment: Interesting solution. Unfortunately doesn't work well for my use case. There's no gaurentee that the nils are right padding my array, which means I'm at risk of any duplicated number at the end getting eliminated. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: No you're not, it will only pop nils (and falses)

Comment: Hmm, I didn't expect this to be the accepted answer. I actually agree with @steenslag. Maybe better or more realistic is: `a.pop until a.empty? or a.last`

Comment: Or better `a.pop while a.last.nil?` to avoid losing all trailing false's.

Comment: stumbled across this, small bug, you will get infinite loop if all the values are nil, need to add a size condition:

a.pop while a.last.nil? && a.size>0

Answer (score 3):

```
foo = [1, 2, nil, nil, 3, nil, 4, 5, 6, nil, nil, nil]
foo.reverse.drop_while(&:nil?).reverse
# [1, 2, nil, nil, 3, nil, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner for you :)

```
a =  [1, 2, nil, nil, 3, nil, 4, 5, 6, nil, nil, nil] 

a[0..a.rindex{|el| !el.nil?}] # => [1, 2, nil, nil, 3, nil, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!(a = ar.pop)){}; ar.push a
```

Still an ugly loop, but maybe less ugly?